# Running Multiple RTL-SDR Applications using a Single Dongle

Tags: troubleshooting, rtl-sdr

I want to run two applications in my Raspberry Pi (model B):

1. Weather stellite tracking;
2. Airplane tracking with dump1090.

I have installed the RTL software and scripts from [this tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-NOAA-Weather-Satellite-Receiver/) for the weather satellite project and can confirm it is working. Since the scripts for this project schedule the use of the dongle throughout the day, I thought I could use the dongle with [Virtual Radar and Mono](http://www.virtualradarserver.co.uk/Mono.aspx) to do airplane tracking when the antenna is not litening for th NOAA satellites.

I have noticed that Virtual Radar is not always able to dectect my RTL dongle eventhough the next scheduled listening for NOAA is still a few hours away. This makes me wonder if using the same hardware for two projects is even possible.

Have any of you implemented multiple simultaneous SDR projects using the Pi before? What are some best practices I should keep in mind to make this work?

Comment: Interesting question. Unfortunately, it appears there are some here who consider your question "off-topic" for this forum. Personally, and FWIW, I consider it very much "on-topic". I don't have an answer for you now as I'm unfamiliar with Virtual Radar, but I'll take a look to see what I can find.

Comment: A quick search ***suggests*** that your objective may be *problematic*.  This due to the varying antenna requirements for ADS and NOAA satellite reception. ADS requires a vertically polarized antenna tuned for 1090 MHz, whereas NOAA satellite reception requires a RH-Circular-polarized antenna tuned for 137 MHz. In addition, *Virtual Radar* seems to be a made-for-Windows app that requires a not-ready-for-prime-time app called `mono` for use with Linux... and I've not seen *Virtual Radar* used in a similar application. I'm curious: did you read something suggesting this was possible??

Comment: Hi @Seamus, thanks for your help!

I am able to run both projects separately, although the Virtual Radar one is not working properly. That said I am using a single antenna (the only one I have) for both projects. It is better suited for the 1090 MHz range.
As for Virtual Radio itself I just assumed it would work on a Debian distro on the basis of what they provide with their [installation intructions](https://www.virtualradarserver.co.uk/Mono.aspx) (using `mono`). So far, the `dump1090` software is working great, but it is not properly interfacing with Virtual Radar like it is supposed to.